# Dynamic 'Property' count on applicable foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I currently have the following three models in my app:

**Models.py**

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Event(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Invite(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

On my index page for the Event model where I show a single event, I also show a list of all guests that could possibly be added to the event:

```
guests = Guest.objects.filter(wedding = event.wedding).order_by("tag", "name")
```

However, in the table, I would like to show next to each guest how many invites for this specific event they have been given.

While I could do a property on the guest, its possible that multiple guests could be invited to multiple events.

In an ideal world, I would define a property that accepts the event as a parameter so I could do something like this in the template:

```
{% for guest in guests %}
{{ guest.name }} ( {{ guest.total_invites(event.id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can switch to `Jinja2` template renderer (really great IMO and much more convenient) - it allows to write exactly like that. Or you can [create custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) for that purpose and call in template like `guest|total_invites_for_guest:event.id`.

Comment: Or, if you show only single event on page, you can just define `total_invites` method on `Guest` model, do `guests = [(g, g.total_invites(event)) for g in Guest.objects.filter(...).order_by(...)]` in view and then iterate `{% for guest, total_invites in guests %}...` in template